# Is $\langle f - m, m \rangle = 0$ sufficient for $m$ to be an orthogonal projection?

Tags: hilbert-spaces, orthogonality, projection

I was looking at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_projection_theorem and I wondered about the following statement, but I wasn't able to prove or disprove it.

Suppose that $M$ is a subspace of a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ and that $f \in \mathcal{H}$. If $m \in M\setminus 0$ has $\langle f - m, m \rangle = 0$, then is it true that $\langle f - m, m' \rangle = 0$ for all $m' \in M$?

Comment: Of course not: $g\perp m\in M$ does not imply $g\perp M$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Counterexample:

Consider $\mathcal{H} = \mathbb{R}^{3}$ with the standard inner product $\langle (a,b,c), (d,e,f) \rangle = ad + be + cf$, and $M = \operatorname{span}\{(1,0,0), (0,1,0)\}$. Take $m = (1,0,0)$ and $f = (1,1,1)$. It follows that
$$\langle f -m , m \rangle = \langle(0,1,1), (1,0,0) \rangle = 0,$$
but for $m' = (0,1,0) \in M$ we have that
$$\langle f - m , m' \rangle = \langle (0,1,1), (0,1,0) \rangle = 1\not= 0. $$

Answer (score 1):

Counterexample: $m=(0,1)\in M=\mathcal H=\Bbb R^2$ (with its standard inner product) and $m'=f-m=(1,0)$.

Comment: I specified $m \in M \setminus 0$.

Comment: Oops sorry, I just adapted my answer.

Comment: Why the downvote, please?

Comment: The downvote wasn't me but it may be because your answer is quite similar to the other provided answer (the only difference being that you have M = H which might appear less general). Nonetheless, I have now upvoted your response to thank you for providing another example.

Comment: @HarryPartridge Thank you very much. @ Downvoter: I devoted myself to provide the simplest example (and smallest dimensions) possible.